# Role "api-platform" does not exist

Tags: api-platform.com

After intstalation of API Platform I received this error linked to postgres docker `postgres:10-alpine` setup.

bookshop-api git:(master) ✗ `bin/console doctrine:database:create`

```
In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 73:                                                                      
  An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  role "api-platform" does not exist  

In PDOConnection.php line 31:
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  role "api-platform" does not exist                                                   

In PDOConnection.php line 27:                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  role "api-platform" does not exist
```

`.env` file is update according to `docker-compose.yml`, alse the default `api/config/packages/doctrine.yaml` have been changed to use `postgresql`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a conflict with local instance of postgres running on the same port.